# Clickfunnels: After form is submitted, how do you add the email field value to the URL as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, parameters

Currently in general tab I have a URL similar to this for "On Submit Go"

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/script?mid=13&req=4&tid=4
```

I want to be able to do something like this after someone submits a clickfunnels form:

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/script?mid=13&req=4&tid=4&email=#EMAIL#
```

I know that clickfunnels uses merge tags and that the email merge tag is #EMAIL#.

Anybody know how I can add the email field value as a parameter to my URL?

Comment: you can ask to the support of click funnel.

Comment: I tried and they directed me to a CF developer or CF fb group which wasn't really much help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked all the cookies but did not find one that stores the email. Clickfunnels customer support refused to answer the  question. So I opened up the Console in Chrome and eventually figured out that the user email is stored in the local storage.

To access local storage in javascript:

var useremail = localStorage.getItem("Key");

Where Key is the name of the storage variable. This will be different for different domain names on Clickfunnels. The Console on Chrome gives me the Key. It worked beautifully.

localStorage is a html5 thing (sorry, I am not a programmer so don't  know the technical term). This may not work for all browsers, but is supported by the newer versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera and Safari. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Clickfunnels uses cookies to store all data, if you visit any of your live funnel with query string in it, all variables will be saved as cookies and you can access those via JQuery/JS, I'm not sure what is the name of cookie used by CF to store email field, but you can set your own cookie and on next page of funnel access that cookie and redirect to your desire URL with email variable in query string like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              var uri = $.cookie("email");
              window.location = "https://google.com/?email="+uri;
            }, 5000);
        };
</script>
```